# Deleting collection and inserting array of docs via mongoDB Realm webhook

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm

I have a use case where I want to send the contents of a csv file to a mongoDB collection whenever the file is modified. I found that a webhook could be created in mongoDB Realm. The intention of code below is to do 2 things. First, drop a specified collection in a specified db. Second, to insert many (~10k+) documents to the specified collection.

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
    const {database, coll_to_update} = payload.query;
    const contentTypes = payload.headers["Content-Type"];
    const body = payload.body;

    console.log("database, coll_to_update:", database, coll_to_update);
    console.log("Content-Type:", JSON.stringify(contentTypes));
    console.log("Request body:", body);

    const coll = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db(database).collection(coll_to_update);
    
    coll.deleteMany({})
      .then(result => console.log(`Deleted ${result.deletedCount} item(s).`))
      .catch(err => console.error(`Delete failed with error: ${err}`))
    
    coll.insertMany(body)
      .then(result => console.log(`Successfully inserted ${result.insertedIds.length} items!`))
      .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert documents: ${err}`))

    return payload;
};
```

This is being written in the Function editor in the online Realm UI. Because I could not find a way to drop the collection, I tried to delete all documents from it by passing an empty query. But I get an error saying `FunctionError: mongodb delete: no arguments were passed`. I am able to delete documents if I provide a query. Is there any query that would always match all documents I could use, or a better way to drop or delete all in a collection?

The second issue is I am not sure how to decode the contents of the csv sent in the request body. The curl I am using is below. Just for testing, I also sent it to http://httpbin.org/post and the json is decoded correctly as an array of two objects:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d [{\"foo\":\"bar\"},{\"baz\":\"zap\"}] \
"https://eu-west-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/application-0- \
abcdef/service/mongo_doodah/incoming_webhook/webhook0? \
database=FIC&coll_to_update=FIC_data&secret=not_this_one"
```

When sending to the Realm endpoint however, I get error `FunctionError: mongodb insert: argument must be an array`. Checking the logs I see:

```
Logs:
[
  "database, coll_to_update: FIC FIC_data",
  "Content-Type: [\"application/json\"]",
  "Request body: [object Binary]"
]

Body:
{
  "$binary": {
    "base64": "W3siZm9vIjoiYmFyIn0seyJiYXoiOiJ6YXAifV0=",
    "subType": "00"
  }
}
```

So Realm is working differently to, for example, pastebin in how it handles the json I sent. I cannot figure out how to get the json I sent out of this binary object within the Realm webhook editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a couple of points of interest that may help your cause.  First, let me provide my solution.  I used an Atlas Realm webhook with the following attributes:

- Authentication: System
- Log Function Arguments: ON
- HTTP Method: POST
- Respond With Result: ON
- Can Evaluate:
- Request Validation: No Additional Authorization

Of these items, I think the HTTP Method is the most relevant.  Since you are passing data in your CURL command using the -d operator a GET method will not suffice.  Your CURL command did not specify an HTTP verb so it assumes GET.  The second item is request validation.  I see your URL includes the special `secret` key item.  I am not using any validation because I am focused on having the function work as expected, then I would apply security.

**Web Hook Function**

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
  
    const {database, coll_to_update} = payload.query;
    const contentTypes = payload.headers["Content-Type"];
    const body = JSON.parse(payload.body.text());
    
    // console.log("database, coll_to_update:", database, coll_to_update);
    // console.log("Content-Type:", JSON.stringify(contentTypes));
    // console.log("Request body:", body);

    const coll = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db(database).collection(coll_to_update);
    
    coll.deleteMany({})
     .then(result => { 
        console.log(`Deleted ${result.deletedCount} item(s).`)
       
        coll.insertMany(body)
          .then(result => console.log(`Successfully inserted ${result.insertedIds.length} items!`))
          .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert documents: ${err}`))
     })
     .catch(err => console.error(`Delete failed with error: ${err}`))
    
     return payload;
};
```

Notice the constant variable `body` is assigned the JSON parsed version of the `.text()` representation of the binary payload?  This converts the $binary to a JSON object.

The second item to mention is order of operations.  Your original post had the calls to the database sequentially - one after another.  You first call `deleteMany()` then you call `insertMany()`.  But since the code is asynchronous the call to insertMany occurred before the deleteMany and as such the inserted records never show.  Instead, place the insert inside the `.then()` of the `deleteMany()`.

Here is my CURL command.  You must ensure the HTTP verb matches the web hook method.  In my case I elected to use POST in both.

**Example CURL Command**

```
curl --verbose \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST "https://us-east-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/barryapp-pzhuy/service/barryservice/incoming_webhook/barrywebhook?database=FIC&coll_to_update=FIC_data&secret=not_this_one" \
  --data '[ { "foo": "bar" }, { "baz": "zap" } ]'
```

**Example mongoshell Documents**

```
Enterprise atlas-7aocnr-shard-0 [primary]> db.FIC_data.find()
[
  { _id: ObjectId("614b649faed0b6812c95e976"), foo: 'bar' },
  { _id: ObjectId("614b649faed0b6812c95e977"), baz: 'zap' }
]
```

To test this out, I needed to pass a different payload and verify in the database all the records changed...

**Test by issuing a second CURL command**

```
curl --verbose \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST "https://us-east-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/barryapp-pzhuy/service/barryservice/incoming_webhook/barrywebhook?database=FIC&coll_to_update=FIC_data&secret=not_this_one" \
  --data '[ { "foo": "abc" }, { "baz": "xyz" } ]'
```

**Results in mongoshell**

```
Enterprise atlas-7aocnr-shard-0 [primary]> db.FIC_data.find()
[
  { _id: ObjectId("614b6537b435654ce5212d90"), foo: 'abc' },
  { _id: ObjectId("614b6537b435654ce5212d91"), baz: 'xyz' }
]
```

Oh, and by the way, I confirmed with MongoDB - there is no `drop()` method allowed for a collection using the MongoDB Atlas Realm functions.  To clear a collection you must remove all records as you are doing in your code.  This is not a great solution.  Another solution might be to simply abandon the collection in favor of a new collection name, maybe one with a date in the name.  You could have a cron job clear out the abandoned collections with a collection.drop() command to avoid the overhead of deleting records one at a time (especially important if the collection is large on a replica set topology where the deletes are idempotent commands on the OpLog).

Generally speaking database operations are not allowed.  I am unclear on all the limitations surrounding this concept but if a collection drop is not allowed I suspect index topics are also not allowed.

Comment: The curl command I use works as expected, i.e. it does send the data and uses POST to match the webhook setting I selected. Maybe it automatically uses POST since -d is set? I took the curl command from the the example provided on the Settings page of my webhook.

Comment: Even tho I managed this after giving up hope of an answer here and I like my code more (yeah, I'm biased), I'll accept yours since I had a bounty up for it. Surprised this did not get more answers, in hindsight it is a pretty basic question!

Comment: @msm1089 - Thanks for the points.  Just an FYI - the insertMany() is performing an ordered bulk operation - it only submits the entire payload to the database once, so I would expect the same performance from both solutions.  If you prefer the syntax of the bulkOp then it is a better option.  Since you are using the bulkOp() structures, you might find an unordered bulk write to be more performant.  Also, how you deal with a failed insert would be an important aspect.  For ordered bulk ops any error stops the list of inserts at the error point and does not rollback the successful records.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out, see the code below. This does not include the deleting of existing documents in the target collection yet.

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
    const {database, coll_to_update} = payload.query;        
    const coll = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db(database).collection(coll_to_update);

    // Payload body is a JSON string, convert into a JavaScript Object
    const data = JSON.parse(payload.body.text());

    // Perform operations as a bulk
    const bulkOp = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    data.forEach((document) => {
        bulkOp.insert(document);
    });
    response.addHeader(
        "Content-Type",
        "application/json"
    );
    bulkOp.execute().then(() => {
        // All operations completed successfully
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        response.setBody(JSON.stringify({
            timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()
        }));
        return;
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Catch any error with execution and return a 500
        response.setStatusCode(500);
        response.setBody(JSON.stringify({
            timestamp: (new Date()).getTime(),
            errorMessage: error
        }));
        return;
    });
```